# Why is the Tk canvas so slow?

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I wrote cellular automaton (Conway's Game of Life) using Perl and TK, just for fun and practice. It works fine with console output. When I use TK, in first version I just delete and add new cells (rectangles), and after about 100 steps my program has slowed down (about 10 times). Then I rewrote graphics part: initially made all of 2500 cells (50x50) and then changing their color instead of adding/deleting them. But after 600-700 steps my reworked automaton begins to slow down too.

**This is a feature/bug of TK or I do something wrong?**

Changing color by tag:

```
$canvas->itemconfigure("cell"."$x $y", -fill=>'blue');
```

Creating grid:

```
for($y = 0; $y < 50; $y++)
{
    for($x = 0; $x < 50; $x++)
    {
        $canvas->createRectangle($x * 10, $y * 10, ($x + 1) * 10, ($y  + 1) * 10, -fill=>'white', -tags=>["cell"."$x $y"]);
    }
}
```

Start and stop loop:

```
sub start
{
    $repeat = $MainWindow->repeat($speed, sub{&maketurn;});
    # Function "maketurn" is not important, it is a simple counting of "alive" cells
    # and changing color by tag
}

sub stop
{
    if(defined($repeat))
    {
        $repeat->cancel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an articles about the tk canvas widget being slow with many items. The problem sounds very similar to your problem:

http://code.activestate.com/lists/perl-tk/17282/

The solution may be to use the tk photo widget which behaves much like a bitmap. This would be a little of a pain to adapt your code to but it seems like the canvas widget is inherently slow with many objects.

Comment: Create and working with an image instead of drawing rectangles? Ok, I'll try this

Comment: @spyder The canvas is a structured hypergraphics widget. That's great, except it sucks at individual pixels (as each graphics element has a complex object model). For pixel work, a photo image is far more efficient.

Comment: That URL now gives a 404